# IntelliJ Velocity template $Character.isUpperCase return false on uppercase char

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I'm trying to make a setter template which will allow me to use a m prefix for member variables. So when I have a field `mTest` is should give me a setter: `public setTest` and not `setmTest`. I think I have the correct logic, but `Character.isUpperCase` returns false even if it's a upper case letter. I've added some debugging a bit improvised, since it's kind of weird to test, because IntelliJ check if there is a proper function returned. When generating a setter I get an error dialog where I can see my output of:

```
#if($Character.isUpperCase($paramName.charAt(1)))
  paramIsUppercase: $paramName.charAt(1)
#else
  paramIsNotUppercase: $paramName.charAt(1)
#end
```

Complete code:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))

// debugging
#if($Character.isUpperCase($paramName.charAt(1)))
  paramIsUppercase: $paramName.charAt(1)
#else
  paramIsNotUppercase: $paramName.charAt(1)
#end

#if($StringUtil.startsWith($paramName, 'm') && $Character.isUpperCase($paramName.charAt(1)))
    #set($paramName = $paramName.substring(1))
#end
#set($paramName = $StringUtil.decapitalize($paramName))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static void ##
#else
  $classname ##
#end
set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($paramName))($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
#if(!$field.modifierStatic)
return this;
#end
}
```

When using this to create a setter for `mTest` I get an error for my debugging

> paramIsNotUppercase: T

Why is this returning false and is there a fix for this?

Comment: Bug report [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that `$Character` is not defined, which means the expression will always return `false`. There is a way to get around this. It is a horrible hack, but it works for me. Use the following template lines.

```
## get some object
#set($String='')
## abuse it to obtain the desired jdk class
#set($Character=$String.class.forName('java.lang.Character'))
```

After that you can use `$Character` regularly as you desire (i.e. `$Character.isUpperCase($paramName.charAt(1))`).

However there is no need to create your own setter template if you want to use prefixes for fields. Just go to the settings *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation* and specify a *Name prefix* for *Field* and getters and setters will be generated correctly.

Comment: I have no problems creating a getter or setter for either prefixed or unprefixed fields. Maybe you are running into a bug?

Comment: I have added an explanation for why isUpperCase returns false and a hack to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad you don't get an error thrown for such a thing. But now I know stuff like that can return false.